# Advanced Form Submission -Radios, Checkboxes, and redirects

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an advanced form that switches divs based on user selection of radios and checkboxes. I need to capture this data and have it submitted in email on form submit. Below is the HTML and PHP I have so far. Based on testing Ive done it does not send the email, and it does not redirect, so Im not even sure if its capturing the data that Ive logged so far.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="survey.php" class="" id="new_signup_context" method="post" data-abide>

            <div class='choose_level tile'> 

                <div class='row'>

                    <div class='large-12 columns'>

                        <h2>What are you looking for?</h2>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class='row'>

                    <div class='large-6 columns opt1a'>

                        <label class='select' data-level='custom' for='level_custom'>

                        <img data-level='custom' src='img/51.png'>

                        </label>

                        <h3>Custom</h3>

                        <input id='level_custom' name='level1' type='radio' value='custom'>

                        <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='custom' for='level_custom'></label>

                    </div>

                    <div class='large-6 columns opt1b'>

                        <label class='select' data-level='townhome' for='level_townhome'>

                        <img data-level='townhome' src='img/aspen.png'>

                        </label>

                        <h3>Townhome</h3>

                        <input id='level_townhome' name='level1' type='radio' value='townhome'>

                        <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='townhome' for='level_townhome'></label>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        <!-- Custom Tier 1 -->

        <div class='choose_style tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpDesigns'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>Pick the style(s) of home you like.</h2>

                    <div class='store_errors errors'></div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row homes'>

                <div class='hometype large-3 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='prairie'>

                        <img src='img/prairie.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='prairie' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Prairie'>                   

                </div>

                <div class='hometype large-3 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='traditional'>

                        <img src='img/traditional.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='traditional' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Traditional'>

                </div>

                <div class='hometype large-3 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='transitional'>

                    <img src='img/transitional.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='transitional' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value='Transitional'>

                </div>

                <div class='hometype large-3 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='bungalow'>

                        <img src='img/bungalow.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='bungalow' name='hometypes' type='checkbox' value="Bungalow">

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button homes hidden centered'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse homes">Continue &rarr;</button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 1 -->

        <!-- Townhome Tier 1 -->

        <div class='choose_layout tile centered hidden' data-behavior='LayoutStyle'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>Pick the layout you like best.</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-6 columns'>

                    <label class='select' data-level='levelb' for='level_b'>

                        <img data-level='levelb' src='img/floorB.jpg'>

                    </label>

                    <h3>Level B</h3>

                    <input id='level_b' name='signup_context[layout_level]' type='radio' value='Level B'>

                    <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='levelb' for='level_b'></label>

                </div>

                <div class='large-6 columns'>

                    <label class='select' data-level='levelc' for='level_c'>

                        <img data-level='levelc' src='img/floorC.jpg'>

                    </label>

                    <h3>Level C</h3>

                    <input id='level_c' name='signup_context[layout_level]' type='radio' value='Level C'>

                    <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='levelc' for='level_c'></label>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Townhome Tier 1 -->

        <!-- Custom Tier 2 -->

        <div class='choose_town tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpTowns'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>Pick the town(s) you are interested in.</h2>

                    <div class='store_errors errors'></div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row towns'>

                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='deerfield'>

                        <img src='img/deerield.png' >

                    </label>

                    <input id='deerfield' name='town' type='checkbox' value='Deerfield'>

                </div>

                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='highland_park'>

                        <img src='img/highlandpark.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='highland_park' name='town' type='checkbox' value='Highland Park'>

                </div>


                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='northbrook'>

                        <img src='img/northbrook.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='northbrook' name='town' type='checkbox' value='Northbrook'>

                </div>

                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='glenview'>

                        <img src='img/glenview.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='glenview' name='town' type='checkbox' value="Glenview">

                </div>

                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='wilmette'>

                        <img src='img/wilmette.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='wilmette' name='town' type='checkbox' value='Wilmette'>

                </div>

                <div class='preftown large-2 columns'>

                    <div class='checked'></div>

                    <label for='other'>

                        <img src='img/other.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='other' name='town' type='checkbox' value='Other'>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button tbutton hidden'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_towns">Continue &rarr;</button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 2 -->

        <!-- Custom Tier 3 -->

        <div class='choose_land tile centered hidden' data-behavior='Land'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>Do you Own or Need land?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-6 columns'>

                    <label class='select' data-level='own' for='level_own'>

                        <img data-level='own' src='img/own.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='level_own' name='signup_context[layout_level]' type='radio' value='own'>

                    <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='own' for='level_own'></label>

                </div>

                <div class='large-6 columns'>

                    <label class='select' data-level='need' for='level_need'>

                        <img data-level='need' src='img/need.png'>

                    </label>

                    <input id='level_need' name='signup_context[layout_level]' type='radio' value='need'>

                    <label class='button blue_button select' data-level='need' for='level_need'></label>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 3 -->

        <!-- Custom Tier 4 -->

        <div class='timeframe tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpYourTimeframe'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>What is your timeframe?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row sizes'>

                <div class='timeframes'>

                    <div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="signup_context_height"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Timeframe</label>

                        <select class="select required timeframe_dropdown" id="signup_timeframe" name="timeframe">

                            <option value="now">0-3 months</option>
                            <option value="soon">3-6 months</option>
                            <option value="later">6-9 months</option>
                            <option value="someday">9-12 months</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class='large-2 columns last'></div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button timeframeb'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_timeframe">Continue &rarr;</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 4 -->

        <!-- Townhome Tier 2 -->

        <div class='timeframeB tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpYourTimeframeB'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>What is your timeframe?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row sizes'>

                <div class='timeframes'>

                    <div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="signup_context_height"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Timeframe</label>

                        <select class="select required timeframeB_dropdown" id="signup_timeframe" name="timeframeB">

                            <option value="now">0-3 months</option>
                            <option value="soon">3-6 months</option>
                            <option value="later">6-9 months</option>
                            <option value="someday">9-12 months</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button timeframebB'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_timeframe">Continue &rarr;</button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Townhome Tier 2 -->

        <!-- Custom Tier 5 -->

        <div class='homesize tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpYourSize'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>What size home do you want?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row sizes'>

                <div class='size'>

                    <div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="signup_context_size"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Size</label>

                        <select class="select required custom_dropdown" id="Select1" name="size">

                            <option value="2500">2500 sq.ft</option>
                            <option value="2800">2800 sq.ft</option>
                            <option value="3000">3000 sq.ft</option>
                            <option value="3200">3200 sq.ft</option>
                            <option value="3500">3500 sq.ft</option>
                            <option value="4000+">4000+ sq.ft</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button sizeb'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_size">Continue &rarr;</button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 5 -->

        <!-- Custom Tier 6 -->

        <div class='homeprice tile centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpYourSize'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>What is your budget?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row prices'>


                <div class='price'>

                    <div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="signup_context_size"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Price</label>

                        <select class="select required custom_dropdown" id="Select2" name="price">

                            <option value="850">$850,000</option>
                            <option value="900">$900,000</option>
                            <option value="950">$950,000</option>
                            <option value="1M">$1M</option>
                            <option value="1.1">$1.1M</option>
                            <option value="1.2+">$1.2M+</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button pricesb centered'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_price">Continue &rarr;</button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Custom Tier 6 -->

        <!-- Townhome Tier 3 -->

        <div class='priceB tile centered hidden' data-behavior='your_priceB'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>What is your budget?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row prices'>

                <div class='priceB'>

                    <div class="input select required"><label class="select required" for="signup_context_size"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Price</label>

                        <select class="select required custom_dropdown" id="Select2" name="priceB">

                            <option value="240">$240,000</option>
                            <option value="280">$280,000</option>
                            <option value="300">$300,000</option>
                            <option value="325">$325,000</option>
                            <option value="350">$350,000+</option>

                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='fixed_button pricesbB'>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse continue_price">Continue &rarr;</button>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Endof Townhome Tier 3 -->

        <!-- Form -->

        <div class='contactForm centered hidden' data-behavior='SignUpYourInfo'>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class='large-12 columns'>

                    <h2>How can we get in touch with you?</h2>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class='row'>

                <div class="large-12 columns">

                    <p class="contact-name">

                        <label>Your name <small>required</small></label>

                        <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" name="surveyName">

                        <small class="error">Name is required and must be a string.</small>

                    </p>

                    <p class="contact-email">

                        <label>Email <small>required</small></label>

                        <input type="email" required name="surveyEmail">

                        <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>

                    </p>

                    <p class="contact-phone">

                        <input id="contact_phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" name="phone" />

                    </p>

                    <p class="contact-message">

                        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="surveyMessage" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>

                    </p>

                    <p class="contact-submit">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" id="submit">Submit</button>

                    </p>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>  

        <!-- Endof Form -->

        </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = trim($_POST["surveyName"]);
        $email = trim($_POST["surveyEmail"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["surveyMessage"]);

        $email_body = "";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message  . "<br>"; 
        $email_body = $email_body   if (isset($level1) && $level1=="custom") echo "checked" . "<br>";
        $email_body = $email_body   if (isset($level1) && $level1=="townhome") echo "checked" . "<br>";




        $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
        $address = "cmell@thejacobscompanies.net";
        $mail->Subject    = "Contact Form Submission | " . $name;
        $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

        header("Location: www.thejacobscompanies.net/#services");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate `$email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";` add a dot before the `=` as in `$email_body .= $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";` and do the same for the others. That is one of the issues here.

Comment: Also, your redirect doesn't work because of the missing `http://` in `header("Location: www.thejacobscompanies.net/#services");` change it to `header("Location: http://www.thejacobscompanies.net/#services");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually his building of the $email_body is correct since he is concatenating to the old $email_body in each statement. I think you are just used to seeing it done using the .= shortcut operator so seeing it in this form is a red flag.  If he did use the .= operator though his statements should become $email_body .= "Name: " . $name . "<br>"; rather than $email_body .= $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>"; which will give him duplicate text message text.

Comment: I guess I'm just so used to seeing it done the other way around as you stated. I can see it here now `$email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";` however I don't see the concatenate in `$email_body = $email_body   if (isset($level1)...` @elitechief21

Comment: I made the header change and it still does not send email or redirect. Thoughts?

Comment: For this line $email_body = $email_body if (isset($level1) && $level1=="custom") echo "checked" . "<br>"; and the other like it should have the if statement surrounding the statement like so if (isset($level1) && $level1=="townhome"){$email_body .= "checked";}.  The way those two statements are written is syntactically incorrect and is probably why the script isn't working

Comment: I could not fully test your code because I'm obviously missing the libraries to go with it. However, I was able to determine that both lines containing both of your `if` conditions, is part of the problem. @user3032873 Try putting those conditions underneath `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {`

Comment: Plus, your redirect won't work until mail is successfully sent and your `if` conditions fixed. @user3032873

Comment: Try what `elitechief21` mentioned [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640530/advanced-form-submission-radios-checkboxes-and-redirects#comment30897677_20640530) about the `if` conditions. Most likely the issue here. @user3032873

Comment: I posted something for you below to try out. @user3032873

Comment: Have you tried what I posted below? @user3032873

Comment: It didnt work. But could the problem be my Localhost: setup?

Comment: FYI you never call the `send()` method of `$mail`(assuming you are using phpmailer.php). Also, If you don't have a mail server installed on your local machine and you didn't change the default mail server in php.ini from localhost to an actual mail server the email won't work.

Comment: Have a look at my **EDIT**, as per `elitechief21's` comment. @user3032873

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

As per `elitechief21's` comment, I found this bit of code:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

which I assume could be placed below `$mail->MsgHTML($email_body);`

**Note:** However, you will need to replace the successful `echo` with `header...` but not use both.

---

### Answer for testing purposes only.

As per comments already given by `elitechief21` and myself, try this to see if it will work.

```
<?php 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = trim($_POST["surveyName"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["surveyEmail"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["surveyMessage"]);

    $email_body = "";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
    $email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message  . "<br>"; 

if (isset($level1) && $level1=="custom"){$email_body .= "checked";}
if (isset($level1) && $level1=="townhome"){$email_body .= "checked";}

    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $address = "cmell@thejacobscompanies.net";

    $mail->Subject    = "Contact Form Submission | " . $name;
    $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

    header("Location: http://www.thejacobscompanies.net/#services");

    exit;
}
?>
```

---

### EDIT for POST variables

You can play around with any of the following:

```
foreach($var as $key=>$value) {
echo $value;
}
```

and/or:

```
foreach($_POST['var'] as $key=>$value) {
echo $value;
```

You could use this also, that will iterate through all `POST` values:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
echo "$key=$value";
}
```

Also, assuming `$_POST['item_name_1']`

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'item_name_') === 0) {
        echo "$k = $v";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can just output in the email everything, like a var_dump, and I can sort through the checked radios and boxes from the email?

Comment: This could be an option, for example: `foreach($_POST['var'] as $key=>$value) { echo $value; }` @user3032873

Comment: This is PHPmailer, I don't know enough about it to implement it. But I can add a piece of code in an edit that you can play around with. @user3032873

Comment: Have a look under my **EDIT for POST variables** @user3032873 other than that, I wish I could help further. However, if my original answer helped to resolved the mailing issue, we should close this question by clicking the white checkmark till it turns green. Cheers